# MPI nonblocking send and receive don't communicate

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I am writing an application in C++ with MPI and OpenMPI. My problem is that when I send data with

`MPI_Isend(&interbest,1,MPI_INT,i,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);`

to other slave nodes and try to receive it with

```
MPI_Irecv(&localbest,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
```

the data are simply not transferred (both of the buffer variables are OK).

I am new to MPI, so what could have gone wrong ? I have to use nonblocking versions, since this is used for sharing a best solution that had just been found with other slaves. The other slaves are periodically checking for a new best solution, but even though the solution is clearly sent, no slave will receive it.

The application is running on a MPI cluster combined from 3 servers, communicating with Infiniband.

In case of any further questions please dont hesitate to ask me.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you `MPI_Wait()` on both sides ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I dont, but isn't nonblocking send/receive with a wait the same as a blocking send/receive ? I though the nodes have some sort of a buffer, so I can send a message from one node and continue working and the destination node will check for the message when it can.

Comment: MPI does not guarantee `MPI_ISend()` even start sending the message before `MPI_Wait()` or friends is posted, same thing for `MPI_Irecv()`. So you must make sure your application progresses the communication (which is done internally by `MPI_Wait()`, `MPI_Test()` and other subroutines). Obviously, you do not have to `MPI_Wait()` right after `MPI_Isend()`, but you have to do it at some point in time otherwise your application might hang forever.

Comment: If the problem persists, please edit your question with a [MCVE]